# Power set statement validity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

If A is a set and P(A) is the power set of A.

Why is the following statement is true: ∃C[(C is a set) ∧ (∀A[A is a set → C ∈ P(A)] )]

Comment: Consider $C=\varnothing$.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: No problem. Consider answering the question yourself, so it doesn't come up as answered. Explain why my hint works.

Comment: Note that @GitGud 's example is the only $C$ that works

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, C can only contain the ∅, which satisfies all Power sets of any set, including the power set of A in this example.